# How can I change the Social Club account associated with GTA 5?

Tags: steam, grand-theft-auto-v, rockstar-games-social-club

I have GTA 5 on Xbox 360 and now on PC. I use the same Social Club logins on both accounts.

I have GTA 4 on Steam but with a different Social Club account as at the time 4 was having issues and couldn't link to my existing account. I was playing 5 on the PC when it logged me out.

When I went to log back in it is trying to login to the steam social club (GTA4). GTA5 on the PC isn't running through steam, it is the DVD version. It keeps asking for the activation code, which is linked to my other social club account. I have rebooted to prevent Steam client loading but it is still asking for the activation code on the wrong account.

How do I change the account? I am logged in to the net on the correct account on this PC but it's ignoring it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I booted the PC up without steam client running. Started GTA5 and on the Rockstar social club login screen there's a back button on the bottom left hand side. I clicked that and was able to login with the correct details.
I can't do a screen-shot as now it's going to the correct account I'm not prompted to enter a key and it goes straight in to the game.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I went to the windows button, searched for GTA, deleted all profiles and then when I tried to log in again I had to type in my account info.
Problem solved.

Comment: I had already fixed it before I saw this. Thanks anyway.